# How to use a C# class generated by XSD to serialize/deserialize individual elements of the XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I currently have a C# class that I have generated from an XML schema, this is used to take an XML file and update values in a database.

Where I am stuck is that one of these values (due to complexity and variability) needs to be stored in the database as stand alone xml which I will then need to deserialize at run time.

Is it possible to define a second C# class to handle this one element without interfering with the master class.

Or would it simple be easier to change the name of this node when reserializing it to save?

Edit: My apologies for the lack of context, it was late and I was on my out the door.
The XML file is used to setup web form validation and customization for different clients, at least 80% of the schema is very simple data (making field mandatory, applying regex, and hiding and showing fields are some examples)

The complicated part that I mentioned has to do with conditional validation between multiple fields.  Here is a sample of what the XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<Relationships>
    <Relationship xsi:type="MutuallyExclusiveRelationship">
        <Fields>
            <Field Id="lineItemAfeNumber" IsInGrid="true"/>
            <Field Id="lineItemCostCenter" IsInGrid="true"/>
        </Fields>
    </Relationship>     
</Relationships>

<Fields>

    <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="invoiceNumber">
        <ValidationRegex Value="^[0-9a-zA-Z\-]*$"/>
        <ValidationRegexMessage Value="{0} must be alpha-numeric and can contain dashes."/>
        <MaxLength Value="20"/>
    </Field>

    <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="afeNumber">
        <InputMask Value="aa999999"/>
        <ValidationRegex Value="^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{6}$"/>
        <ValidationRegexMessage Value="{0} must be in the format AA999999."/>
    </Field>

    <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="costCenter">
        <ValidationRegex Value="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
        <ValidationRegexMessage Value="{0} must be alpha-numeric."/>
        <MinLength Value="8"/>
        <MaxLength Value="9"/>
    </Field>


    <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="orderNumber">
        <MinLength Value="1"/>
        <MaxLength Value="12"/>
    </Field>

    <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="generalLedgerCode">
        <InputMask Value="9999.999"/>
        <ValidationRegex Value="^[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{3}$"/>
        <ValidationRegexMessage Value="{0} must be in the format 0000.000."/>
    </Field>

    <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="approverId">
        <Label Value="Approver Code"/>
        <MaxLength Value="10"/>
    </Field>

    <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="leaseWell">
        <Label Value="Location/UWI"/>
    </Field>

    <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="poNumber">
        <ValidationRegex Value="^[a-zA-Z0-9/-]*$"/>
        <ValidationRegexMessage Value="{0} must be alpha-numeric and can contain '-'."/>
        <MaxLength Value="12"/>
    </Field>

    <Field xsi:type="DropDownField" Id="currency">
        <Label Value="Currency"/>
        <DefaultValue Value="CAD"/>
        <Values>
            <DropDownValue Value="USD"/>
            <DropDownValue Value="CAD"/>
        </Values>
    </Field>    

    <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="remitToTax">
        <Label Value="GST/HST #"/>
    </Field>

    <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="detailsComment">
        <Mandatory Value="false"/>
        <MaxLength Value="40"/>
    </Field>    

    <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="newComment">
        <MaxLength Value="40"/>
    </Field>

    <!-- Attachments -->
    <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="attachmentFileName">
        <MandatoryMessage Value="Attachments are required."/>
    </Field>

    <Field xsi:type="DropDownField" Id="approverCompanyCode">
        <Mandatory Value="true"/>
    </Field>

    <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="recipientName">
      <Mandatory Value="true"/>
    </Field>        
</Fields>

<Grids>
    <Grid Id="invoiceDetailsTable">
        <Fields>
            <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="lineItemDescription">
                <MaxLength Value="40"/>
            </Field>                

            <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="lineItemAfeNumber">
                <InputMask Value="aa999999"/>
                <ValidationRegex Value="^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{6}$"/>
                <ValidationRegexMessage Value="{0} must be in the format AA999999."/>
            </Field>

            <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="lineItemCostCenter">
                <ValidationRegex Value="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
                <ValidationRegexMessage Value="{0} must be alpha-numeric."/>
                <MinLength Value="8"/>
                <MaxLength Value="9"/>
            </Field>

            <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="lineItemOrderNumber">
                <MinLength Value="1"/>
                <MaxLength Value="12"/>
            </Field>

            <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="lineItemLeaseWell">
                <Label Value="Location/UWI"/>
                <Mandatory Value="true"/>
            </Field>

            <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="lineItemGlAccount">
                <InputMask Value="9999.999"/>
                <ValidationRegex Value="^[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{3}$"/>
                <ValidationRegexMessage Value="{0} must be in the format 0000.000."/>
            </Field>


            <Field xsi:type="TextField" Id="lineItemPoNumber">
                <ValidationRegex Value="^[a-zA-Z0-9/-]*$"/>
                <ValidationRegexMessage Value="{0} must be alpha-numeric and can contain '-'."/>
                <MaxLength Value="12"/>
            </Field>
        </Fields>
    </Grid>
</Grids>
```

The relationship section here is the part I would like to have reserialized, this is obviously a simple example of what the section could be, there are many more child elements that aren't shown.

Comment: The lack of context and code example doesn't make answering the question any easier you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further investigation and brainstorming we've determined that the two different serialization classes can actually live in different scopes which removes the conflict that I was running into.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you serialize this complex element when you save the master class to database?
For example, if your class is something like this:

```
public class Master
{
    public string simple;
    public Complex complex;
}
```

You can save complex element as xml in db with:

```
void SaveToDB(Stream file)
{
    XmlSerializer masterSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Master));
    Master m = (Master)masterSerializer.Deserialize(file);
    //save m.simple to db
    XmlSerializer complexSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Complex));
    StringWriter complexXmlWriter = new StringWriter();
    complexSerializer.Serialize(complexXmlWriter, m.complex);
    string complexXml = complexXmlWriter.ToString();
    //save complexXml to db
}
```

This way you dont need to change your master class and you can save the complex element in xml.